# TypeError: baseChoiceList.splice is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror, array-splice

I've worked on this for 4 hours and read many related explanations and tried out several of them.  I'm sure I'm missing a simple concept and fix for this error.  Your help much appreciated.

ColorChart.setupAnswerChoices();

```
"setupAnswerChoices": function() {

    var currentChoiceList = sessionStorage.getItem("NE_CURRENT_CHOICE_LIST");
    var baseChoiceList = currentChoiceList.slice();

    console.log ("baseChoiceList " + baseChoiceList);
```

> baseChoiceList 12,17,1,22,27,NCN

```
consol.log  ("currentChoiceList " + currentChoiceList);
```

> currentChoiceList 12,17,1,22,27,NCN

```
    var what = Object.prototype.toString;
    console.log("buttonChoice  " + what.call(buttonChoice));
```

> buttonChoice  [object Array]

```
    console.log("baseChoiceList  " + what.call(baseChoiceList));
```

> baseChoiceList  [object String]

```
var buttonChoice = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var randomButtonIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - i));
    buttonChoice = baseChoiceList.splice(randomButtonIndex,1);
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: baseChoiceList.splice is not a function

Comment: Norman Breau is correct.  Alternative approaches suggested using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse.  However Norman's solution using .split is exactly the light weight direct solution needed in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sessionStorage` (and `localStorage`) both can only store key/value pairs as strings.

So your code:

```
var currentChoiceList = sessionStorage.getItem("NE_CURRENT_CHOICE_LIST");
var baseChoiceList = currentChoiceList.slice();
```

`currentChoiceList` is not an array. It is a string.
`baseChoiceList` is again, a string, which is a copy of `currentChoiceList`. (Strings have a `slice()` method.)

It looks like you actually want to do this:

```
var currentChoiceList = sessionStorage.getItem("NE_CURRENT_CHOICE_LIST");
var baseChoiceList = currentChoiceList.split(',');
```

Strings `split` method accepts a delimiter, to split the string into an array of strings.